# /RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout,SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: ItemOrder in retrofit android

Tags: android

I am trying to display order history of user but again n again face this problem in retrofit android

1. Error is no adapter attached and skipping layout
2. order table not found please help me

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.yashodainfotech.varietycart, PID: 16330
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ItemOrder (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ItemOrder where buyer=186
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:891)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:502)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
    at com.orm.SugarRecord.findWithQuery(SugarRecord.java:166)
    at com.yashodainfotech.varietycart.activity.OrderActivity.refreshAdapter(OrderActivity.java:152)
    at com.yashodainfotech.varietycart.activity.OrderActivity$2.onResponse(OrderActivity.java:99)
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Your table does not exist. Make sure your table name is correct

Comment: Your error is _no such table: ItemOrder (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ItemOrder where buyer=186_

Comment: Uninstall the app and install again.

Answer (score 0):

it means your ItemOrder table not created if there is a ; at the end of your sql String remove that and then clean you data in application setting and delete your app run again

Comment: i am uninstalled the app into my mobile ..bt Item order thable not create and all other table have same problem arries